# Adding extra fields to prevent needing joins

Tags: mysql, sql

In consideration of schema design, is it appropriate to add extra table fields I wouldn't otherwise need in order to prevent having to do a join? Example:

```
products_table
| id | name | seller_id

users_table
| id | username |

reviews_table
| id | product_id | seller_id |
```

For the reviews table, I could use a join on the products table to get the user id of the seller. If I leave it out of the reviews table, I have to use a join to get it. There are often tables where several joins are needed to get at some information where I could just have my app add redundant data to the table instead. Which is more correct in terms of schema design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you add a column `reviews.seller_id` and you populate it with values, and then some weeks later you find that the values aren't always the same as the seller in the `products_table`.

In other words, the following query should always return a count of 0, but what if one day it returns a **count of 6**?

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM products_table AS p
JOIN reviews_table AS r USING (product_id)
WHERE p.seller_id <> r.seller_id
```

Meaning there was some update of one table, but not the other. They weren't both updated to keep the seller_id in sync.

How did this happen? Which table was updated, and which one still has the original seller_id? Which one is correct? Was the update intentional?

You start researching each of the 6 cases, verify who is the correct seller, and update the data to make them match.

Then the next week, the count of mismatched sellers is 1477. You must have a bug in your code somewhere that allows an update to one table without updating the other to match. Now you have a much larger data cleanup project, and a bug-hunt to go find out how this could happen.

And how many other times have you done the same thing for other columns -- copied them into a related table to avoid a join? Are those creating mismatched data too? How would you check them all? Do you need to check them every night? Can they be corrected?

This is the kind of trouble you get into when you use *denormalization*, in other words storing columns redundantly to avoid joins, avoid aggregations, or avoid expensive calculations, to speed up certain queries.

In fact, you don't *avoid* those operations, you just move the work of those operations to an earlier time.

It's *possible* to make it all work seamlessly, but it's a lot more work for the coder to develop and test the perfect code, and fix the subsequent code bugs and inevitable data cleanup chores.

Answer (score 2):

You seem overly concerned about the performance of `JOIN`s.  With proper indexing, performance is not usually an issue.  In fact, there are situations where `JOIN`s are faster -- because the data is more compact in two tables than storing the fields over and over and over again (this applies more to strings than to integers, though).

If you are going to have multiple tables, then use `JOIN`s to access the "lookup" information.  There may be some situations where you want to denormalize the information.  But in general, you don't.  And premature optimization is the root of a lot of bad design.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on each specific case. Purely in terms of schema design, you should not have any redundant columns (see [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)). However, in a real case scenario, sometimes it makes sense to have redundant data; for example, when having performance issues, you can sacrifice some memory in order to make SELECT queries faster.

Answer (score 0):

Adding redundant column today will make you curse tomorrow.If you Handle keys in database properly, performance will not penalize you.